# Is there a way to write a python function that will create 'N' arrays? (see body)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy array that is shape 20, 3. (So 20 3 by 1 arrays. Correct me if I'm wrong, I am still pretty new to python)

I need to separate it into 3 arrays of shape 20,1 where the first array is 20 elements that are the 0th element of each 3 by 1 array. Second array is also 20 elements that are the 1st element of each 3 by 1 array, etc.

I am not sure if I need to write a function for this. Here is what I have tried:
Essentially I'm trying to create an array of 3 20 by 1 arrays that I can later index to get the separate 20 by 1 arrays.

```
a = np.load() #loads file
num=20 #the num is if I need to change array size
num_2=3
for j in range(0,num):
    for l in range(0,num_2):
        array_elements = np.zeros(3)
        array_elements[l] = a[j:][l]
```

This gives the following error:
'''
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
'''
I have also tried making it a dictionary and making the dictionary values lists that are appended, but it only gives the first or last value of the 20 that I need.

Comment: What output you expect?

Comment: I need either an array that is shape (3,1) that has 3 (20,1) arrays in it, or a similar list. Something I can index and use the 20,1 arrays later

Comment: you want to separate each column into an array?

Comment: just transpose your array.

Comment: In `numpy`, a (20,3) array can be desrided as 20 (3,) 1d arrays, not (3,1) shaped.. 
 Check `arr[1].shape`.  Similarly, `arr[:, 1]` is a (20,) shape array, the column, but 1d.  Note the composite index, `[:,1]`.  Do spend more time read the numpy basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want to group your arrays by their index.  There are plenty of ways of doing this. Since numpy does not have a group by method, you have to horizontally split the arrays into a new array and reshape it.

```py
old_length = 3
new_length = 20
a = np.array(np.hsplit(a, old_length)).reshape(old_length, new_length)
```

Edit:  It appears you can achieve the same effect by rotating the array `-90 degrees`.  You can do this by using `rot90` and setting `k=-1` or `k=3` telling numpy to rotate by 90 `k` times.

```
a = np.rot90(a, k=-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array has shape (20, 3), this means it's a 2-dimensional array with 20 rows and 3 columns in each row.

You can access data in this array by indexing using numbers or ':' to indicate ranges. You want to split this in to 3 arrays of shape (20, 1), so one array per column. To do this you can pick the column with numbers and use ':' to mean 'all of the rows'. So, to access the three different columns: `a[:, 0]`, `a[:, 1]` and `a[:, 2]`.

You can then assign these to separate variables if you wish e.g. `arr = a[:, 0]` but this is just a reference to the original data in array a. This means any changes in arr will also be made to the corresponding data in a.

If you want to create a new array so this doesn't happen, you can easily use the `.copy()` function. Now if you set `arr = a[:, 0].copy()`, arr is completely separate to `a` and changes made to one will not affect the other.